# How to replace Windows bootloader with syslinux?

Tags: boot, bootloader, syslinux

I have a dualboot of Windows 7 and Arch Linux. I had to reinstall my Windows, but doing this, the Windows Bootloader took the place of Syslinux. Now how can I place Syslinux back?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a bootable archiso USB and follow the instructions on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/syslinux#Manual_install